# Checking whether pip is installed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, syntax-error

I am using `Python 2.7.12` and I want to check whether the pip is installed or not. For this, in command line of Python application I wrote pip list and pressed enter. However, I get an error like:

```
File"stdin",line 1

pip list

Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

So, how can I solve this issue and get the list of modules as an output?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running pip on python interpreter? Pip is run directly on windows command prompt or linux/mac's terminal, not in python prompt.

Answer (score 37):

Use **command line** and not python.

TLDR; On Windows, do: 
`python -m pip --version`

OR 
`py -m pip --version`

**Details:**

 On Windows, ~> (open windows terminal) 
 `Start (or Windows Key) > type "cmd" Press Enter`
You should see a screen that looks like this
[image]

 *To check to see if pip is installed.*

```
python -m pip --version
```

*if pip is installed, go ahead and use it. for example:*

```
Z:\>python -m pip install selenium
```

if not installed, install pip, *and you may need to
 **[add its path to the environment variables](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/test-runners/add-path-environment-variables)**.* (basic - windows) 
[add path to environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) (basic+advanced)

if python is NOT installed you will get a result similar to the one below 
[image]

Install python. add its path to environment variables.

UPDATE: for newer versions of python
replace "python" with py - see @gimmegimme's comment and link
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: Only, py -m pip --version, worked for me.
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Answer (score 12):

**If you are on a linux machine running Python 2 you can run this commands:**

1st make sure python 2 is installed:

```
python2 --version
```

2nd check to see if pip is installed:

```
pip --version
```

**If you are running Python 3 you can run this command:**

1st make sure python 3 is installed:

```
python3 --version
```

2nd check to see if pip3 is installed:

```
pip3 --version
```

If you do not have pip installed you can run these commands to install pip (it is recommended you install pip for Python 2 and Python 3):

**Install pip for Python 2:**

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Then verify if it is installed correctly:

```
pip --version
```

**Install pip for Python 3:**

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then verify if it is installed correctly:

```
pip3 --version
```

For more info see: https://itsfoss.com/install-pip-ubuntu/

**UPDATE**
I would like to mention a few things. When working with Django I learned that my Linux install requires me to use python 2.7, so switching my default python version for the `python` and `pip` command alias's to python 3 with `alias python=python3` is not recommended. Therefore I use the `python3` and `pip3` commands when installing software like Django 3.0, which works better with Python 3. And I keep their alias's pointed towards whatever Python 3 version I want like so `alias python3=python3.8`.

**Keep In Mind**
When you are going to use your package in the future you will want to use the `pip` or `pip3` command depending on which one you used to initially install the package. So for example if I wanted to change my change my Django package version I would use the `pip3` command and not `pip` like so, `pip3 install Django==3.0.11`.

**Notice**
When running checking the packages version for python: `$ python -m django --version` and python3: `$ python3 -m django --version`, two different versions of django will show because I installed django v3.0.11 with `pip3` and django v1.11.29 with `pip`.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ which pip
```

or

```
 $ pip -V
```

execute this command into your terminal. It should display the location of executable file eg. **/usr/local/bin/pip** and the second command will display the version if the pip is installed correctly.

Comment: Where do you enter the command? In a notebook, cmd (Anaconda or Windows)?

Answer (score 5):

`pip list` is a shell command. You should run it in your shell (bash/cmd), rather than invoke it from python interpreter.

`pip` does not provide a stable API. The only supported way of calling it is via `subprocess`, see [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) and the code at the end of this answer.

However, if you want to just check if `pip` exists locally, without running it, and you are running Linux, I would suggest that you use bash's `which` command:

```
which pip
```

It should show you whether the command can be found in bash's `PATH`/aliases, and if it does, what does it actually execute.

If running `pip` is not an issue, you could just do:

```
python -m pip --version
```

If you really need to do it from a python script, you can always put the import statement into a `try...except` block:

```
try:
    import pip
except ImportError:
    print("Pip not present.")
```

Or check what's the output of a `pip --version` using `subprocess` module:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', '--version'])
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to run `pip list` in bash not in python.

```
pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
argparse (1.4.0)
Beaker (1.3.1)
cas (0.15)
cups (1.0)
cupshelpers (1.0)
decorator (3.0.1)
distribute (0.6.10)
---and other modules
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below command in command line

`python -m ensurepip`

This won't only check if pip is installed, it will also install it if missing. It may or may not be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In CMD, type:

```
pip freeze
```

And it will show you a list of all the modules installed including the version number.

Output:

```
aiohttp==1.1.4
async-timeout==1.1.0
cx-Freeze==4.3.4
Django==1.9.2
django-allauth==0.24.1
django-cors-headers==1.2.2
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-robots==2.0
djangorestframework==3.3.2
easygui==0.98.0
future==0.16.0
httpie==0.9.6
matplotlib==1.5.3
multidict==2.1.2
numpy==1.11.2
oauthlib==1.0.3
pandas==0.19.1
pefile==2016.3.28
pygame==1.9.2b1
Pygments==2.1.3
PyInstaller==3.2
pyparsing==2.1.10
pypiwin32==219
PyQt5==5.7
pytz==2016.7
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6
six==1.10.0
sympy==1.0
virtualenv==15.0.3
xlrd==1.0.0
yarl==0.7.0
```

Comment: OP also said "get the list of modules as an output"

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry.

Comment: this will show the packages installed if there is no package then it will show  nothing